# Installing Ubuntu with windows 10. free space problem

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning

I have windows  10. I have primary partitions in windows and I did some shrinking on one of them and made a 50 GB free space. I wanted to install Ubuntu 16.04 on this, but when I get to the installation part, it does not show any free space available at all.

[image: Screenshot Ubuntu Installer]

Comment: It looks like MBR(msdos) partitioning which has a 4 primary partition limit. You have to convert one primary partition to an extended partition which acts as a container for as many logical partitions as you need. My laptop already has 4 primary partitions: how can I install Ubuntu?
http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu Also make sure Windows fast start up is off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: It would help if you included a screenshot of the *entire* relevant window instead of the forum page you were looking at. That said, your extra space is almost certainly right there as `sda4`. Please fix your image so we can be sure though. Even better, run `sudo parted -l` from a terminal in the Ubuntu live session and show us the output. Are you sure you are looking at the right disk?

Comment: It's impossible to tell from the screen shot you've provided, but another possibility is that you've accidentally created a [dynamic disk (aka LDM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager) configuration, which would require more serious hoop-jumping to fix. See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/354066/installing-ubuntu-on-a-second-non-empty-drive) for more on this topic. ***DO NOTHING ELSE UNTIL YOU DETERMINE IF THIS IS THE CASE!***